# Find the point in a triangle, that is closest to the triangle's 3 points.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I have a project in 10th grade math. we are meant to find a point that is the closest distance to 3 points in a triangle. The purpose is to build a railway station that is closest to 3 landmarks. We have taken a brief look on special segments of triangles in class. (orthocenter, centroid, incenter, and circumcenter). How can I find the point closest to the three points in a triangle? 
Thank you

Excuse my basic knowledge, I think what I mean by "closest" is the shortest average distance from the "railway station" to each of the "landmarks". The purpose of the project is to find the ideal position for the "railway" station. I'd appreciate it if you gave the best options you know of with a brief description that I can then research further. :)

Here is an image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye5fD.jpg

Comment: You have to define what you mean by "closest distance to 3 points" first. Smallest maximum distance? Smallest sum of distances? Smallest sum of squares of distances?

Comment: Gerry Myerson is right, what is meant by closest? May be You are looking for the center of the circumscribed circle, its the point of intersection of the perpendicular bisectors. This has the same distance to all three of the points, namely the radius of the circumsribed circle

Comment: a point cannot be closest to the three vertices simultaneously unless the distances are same. I think this will be the minimum sum of squares of distances or else something like this.

Comment: It generally helps to provide some drawing, even if not neat.

Comment: I have added an image and defined what I mean by "closest". Thank you

Comment: Does this help? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point

Comment: Yes! Thank you! The fermat point works. It is shortest distance sum from all other methods I tried. But why does it work? why is the fermat point the shortest distance?

Comment: There is a simple "mechanical proof" for this minimality property of the Fermat point, see e.g. here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PolyasMechanicalModelForTheFermatPoint/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Fermat point. Read this wiki page for more details
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point

Comment: It would be better to cite the essentials and then post the link